# sequential tasks using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, task, sequence

I'm using vb.net in visual basic 2008. I'm wondering how perfom sequential tasks using vb.net ??

Example :

```
Do Task 1 then Move to Task 2 when Task 1 is complete
```

Any idea Please ? Which things and tools  I have to use to solve this problem ?

Comment: This is the way a program runs anyway: in the order you specify the instructions.  Perhaps you need to explain in more detail what you're doing - your question suggests that you're running multi-threaded code, but you don't make this clear.

Comment: This is a very vague question. What are your tasks doing exactly? Accessing a database? Doing calculations? Generally speaking in .Net things *will happen sequentially* unless you do work to make things execute simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET framework has a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class, which supports `Task continuation`. You would use [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) to chain them together. Here is a code sample:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Form1
  Dim _var1 As Integer = 0

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim task1 As task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf Task1_Code).ContinueWith(AddressOf Task2_Code)
    task1.Wait()
    MessageBox.Show(_var1)
  End Sub

  Sub Task1_Code()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    _var1 = 5
  End Sub

  Sub Task2_Code()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    _var1 *= 5
  End Sub
End Class
```